# Getting an error message while building PhoneGapSample in blackberry Webworks

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am working on PhoneGap BlackberryWebWorks i have install BlackBerry WebWorks plug-in:2.5.1 and Blackberry WebWorks SDK:2.0.0. and PhoneGap 0.9.4.but while building the project in eclipse i am getting the following error

```
  Errors occurred during the build.
  Errors running builder 'Faceted Project Validation Builder' on project 'PhoneGapSample'.
  Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants
```

I am not getting any idea how to proceed ahead to remove this error.If any one have any idea about this. it will help me to overcome from this error.
Thanks,
Sagar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right click on your project >>> Properties >>> Project Facets >>> **uncheck** Static web Module

Hope to help.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but i have done this.now i am having new issue,when i am running my Phonegap webworks app.it gives me file system currupt error.but when i am running my normal BB app it's not showing me any error. i am running both app in the same simulator.

Comment: If you don't have Project Facets available as a menu option then follow neo's directions in the answer below to first install the Java EE Developer Tools. This problem isn't specific to phonegap or blackberry development. They just had additional dependencies in the toolchain which weren't being met with the vanilla Eclipse for Java Developers install.

Comment: In Eclipse-Juno some facets are required. So the problem is with the missing java EE or other libraries/plugins required by the project (when import an existing project to the workspace). The proper fix is given by @Rendall.

Answer (score 44):

Per neo's comment, install **Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools** using the Eclipse -> Help -> Install new software -> Work with -> (your Eclipse version's download repository. e.g.:) Indigo.

In the filter field type, then checkbox, **Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools**.

Download, install, boom: no more errors.  Well, not that error, anyway, YMMV.

Edit: Mayoayres added a comment below that may apply if you still get this error despite following these instructions.  If you find it helpful, upvote his comment!

Comment: This is the proper fix. This happens when an existing project (which requre Java EE plugin) imported to the workspace. @ConnectIT solution won't work as for some projects, facets can not be unchecked.

Comment: You know, Eclipse Juno kind-of sucks.  I have a Static Web Project, no Java EE required, why do I have to install the Java EE Developer Tools to get the plug-in to work property?!?  Sigh.  This worked for me.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: For those who already have 'Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools' installed but nevertheless get this error: Check if you have 'Google Web Toolkit' plugin installed and don't need it. If so, de-install it, that worked for me. Thanks to neo for his comment.

Answer (score 5):

In eclipse juno  there is some cases the project facets doesn't display any contents...it will give a error named "invalid values for project facets"...So there is a need to do the following

```
                 project >>> Properties >>> Builders
```

and uncheck the faceted project validation builder....

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but I found a solution: you need to install into the Eclipse `plugins/` directory the `.jar` for `org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb`, because it seems like you need it, but Eclipse WST doesn't properly depend on it, so it is not always installed when it should be.

The issue is completely unrelated to PhoneGap or Blackberry development, by the way.

Comment: I had the same issue with using Google Web Toolkit (GWT) without having Web Tools Platform (WTP) installed. Solution: Add update site found [here](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/) and just install "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools", then it works.

Comment: I use GWT as well and when I installed Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools from the links neo gave my issue went away as well. I actually think it could stand alone as a separate answer to this question for anyone who encounters the error regardless of if they're doing phonegap or blackberry development.

Answer (score 2):

As a more generic answer, this is because you either imported a project which is dependent on uninstalled Eclipse plugins. I had this issue when migrating to Eclipse Juno. The easiest solution, just edit your .project file in a text editor and remove the conflicting elements. Usually, this is in the buildspec or nature section.

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

Keep a backup of your project file if you're not sure. You may always delete and recreate your project later on. It's easier to remove those references than to find and install the exact missing plugin versions.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using `Thymeleaf Eclipse plugin` for thymeleaf content assist in my project and got these message in Eclipse Juno,

```
Errors running builder 'Thymeleaf Validation Builder' on project 'site'
```

**Solution:**

1. Select project
2. Project -> Properties -> Builders
3. Uncheck the `Thymeleaf Validation Builder`

Uncheck the builder corresponding to your error message and hopefully your problem gets resolved.