# Errors running builder 'Faceted Project Validation Builder' on project 'MyProject'

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, cordova

I am working on Blackberry webworks, Phonegap framework, Apache Ant and configured them in Eclipse 3.6 with sample index.html.

I followed the article [Getting Started with PhoneGap BlackBerry WebWorks](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-BlackBerry-WebWorks)
But I am getting an error message after running the project:

> "Errors running builder 'Faceted Project Validation Builder' on project 'MyProject' "

How do I properly configure the project to support cross-platform?

Comment: Already some one has answered this question

Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936309/getting-an-error-message-while-building-phonegapsample-in-blackberry-webworks

Answer (score 5):

Right click on your project >>> Properties >>> Project Facets >>> uncheck Static web Module.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the previous response and was not very successful.

Do this:-

install Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools using the Eclipse -> Help -> Install new software -> Work with -> (your Eclipse version's download repository. e.g.:) Indigo.

In the filter field type, then checkbox, Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools.

Download and let it install. No more problems.

Answer (score 1):

In the maven web project.

- 1.Clear the maven project.
- 2.Build the maven project.
- 3.Go to the Project Facts on right click on project -> properties -> project facts.
- 4.On the top right side tab select the Runtimes -> select appropriate Apache version(8.5) that is installed on your machine.
- 5.Then Run the project.

It's Solve in my case, try once in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a wrong item in Runtime settings of Project Facets. Right click on project >>> Properties >>> Project Facets >>> Runtime and modify it. [Runtime settings of Project Facets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV0OP.png)